# what is this oracle query doing with the single quotes

Tags: c#, sql, vba, oracle

based on this code,

```
s.Append("table.id").Append(",")
s.Append("column_one || ' ' AS sample_column ").Append(","),
s.Append("column_two || ' ' AS sample_column_two ").Append(","),
...
```

what is the `' '` after the double bars doing? I understand that the `||` is for concating, but not sure what its doing with the single quotes afterward.

`s` is a `StringBuilder` type.

Is the `||` even necessary? Would it be the same to also do it like this? (in C#)

```
s.Append("table.id").Append(",")
s.Append("column_one AS sample_column ").Append(","),
s.Append("column_two AS sample_column_two ").Append(","),
```

Answer (score 2):

> what is the ' ' after the double bars doing? I understand that the || is for concating, but not sure what its doing with the single quotes afterward.

It isn't just single quotes, it is quotes around a single space character. So `' '` is a [text literal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-1824CBAA-6E16-4921-B2A6-112FB02248DA), representing a fixed value of a single space.

It is adding a single space character to the value in the column. At first glance that might not be obvious; these look the same, except in this demo one of the original values is a number so it's being implicitly converted to a string by the first query:

```
select column_name as id, data_type || ' ' AS sample_column , data_length || ' ' AS sample_column_two
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'DUAL';
```

| ID | SAMPLE_COLUMN | SAMPLE_COLUMN_TWO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DUMMY | VARCHAR2 | 1 |

```
select column_name as id, data_type AS sample_column , data_length AS sample_column_two
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'DUAL';
```

| ID | SAMPLE_COLUMN | SAMPLE_COLUMN_TWO |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DUMMY | VARCHAR2 | 1 |

But if you examine the results more closely they are different - the first query has a trailing space after the actual column value, while the second doesn't, making the string length one larger as well, of course:

```
select '<' || id || '>', length(id),
  '<' || sample_column || '>', length(sample_column),
  '<' || sample_column_two || '>', length(sample_column_two)
from (
  select column_name as id, data_type || ' ' AS sample_column , data_length || ' ' AS sample_column_two
  from all_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'DUAL'
);
```

| '<'||ID||'>' | LENGTH(ID) | '<'||SAMPLE_COLUMN||'>' | LENGTH(SAMPLE_COLUMN) | '<'||SAMPLE_COLUMN_TWO||'>' | LENGTH(SAMPLE_COLUMN_TWO) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <DUMMY> | 5 | <VARCHAR2 > | 9 | <1 > | 2 |

```
select '<' || id || '>', length(id),
  '<' || sample_column || '>', length(sample_column),
  '<' || sample_column_two || '>', length(sample_column_two)
from (
  select column_name as id, data_type AS sample_column , data_length AS sample_column_two
  from all_tab_columns
  where table_name = 'DUAL'
);
```

| '<'||ID||'>' | LENGTH(ID) | '<'||SAMPLE_COLUMN||'>' | LENGTH(SAMPLE_COLUMN) | '<'||SAMPLE_COLUMN_TWO||'>' | LENGTH(SAMPLE_COLUMN_TWO) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| <DUMMY> | 5 | <VARCHAR2> | 8 | <1> | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hGF8fzyJ)

It's not clear why your code would be doing that; possibly to convert nulls to a single space (which should be done with `coalesce` or `nvl`), or to force all values to strings (which should be done with `cast` to `to_char`). But if it's there for a reason then you need to find out what that reason is before you remove those trailing spaces.

> Is the || even necessary?

It is necessary if you actually want or need to append a trailing space to those values - again, there *might* be a reason to do it, though it looks a bit odd.

> Would it be the same to also do it like this?

No, the result is different, as those values will no longer have that trailing space.

Answer (score 0):

It concatenates a single white-space at the column value.

In Oracle, an empty string is identical to `NULL` so:

- `SELECT column_one FROM table_name` will either return `NULL` or a string;
- However, `SELECT column_one || ' ' FROM table_name` will always return a string and never a `NULL` value.
- One other alternative would be `COALESCE` or `NVL` but if you used `SELECT COALESCE(column_one, ' ') FROM table_name` then you would not be able to tell if the value was a single space character or a `NULL` character which coalesce has replaced with a space character.

If your C# code is written to always expect a string then that might be the reason to implement it like this (and then you can ignore the last character of the string); however, I would expect most code to be written to handle cases when `NULL` is returned (but maybe the code you are using does not do that).